# If file exists get its contents with batch script

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

I want to access the contents of a JSON file via batch script to do some processing on it. my script is like this:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"
...
...
...
set FILEPATH=C:\\PROGRA~1\\Setup\\setup.json
IF EXIST "%FILEPATH%" (
set string=
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\\PROGRA~1\\Setup\\setup.json) do set "string=!string!%%x"
echo !string!
//do some processing on string variable
)
...
...
```

this script should return file contents but it prints all the environment variables & variables set in this script.

`echo !string!` returns ECHO is off(means string is empty).

if I run this code outside `if()` then it gives correct results(i.e file contents).

```
set string=
for /f "delims=" %%x in (C:\\PROGRA~1\\Setup\\setup.json) do set "string=!string!%%x"
echo !string!
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: You assign `FILEPATH` but do not use it, except for `if exist`. Is there any particular reason why you double all backslashes? You can combine the two `setlocal` commands into one by specifying both arguments for it…

Comment: @aschipfl actually I am checking first that if the directory exists in which the setup.json is situated. So I need to check first if the directory exists and based on that some operations are done. but it also helps in deciding that if setup.json exists or not. So if "C:\\PROGRA~1\\Setup\\" exists then setup.json will also exist. here I wrote ``` set FILEPATH=C:\\PROGRA~1\\Setup\\setup.json ``` to avoid any confusion between the question title and what i am doing in the script. I have used "\\" because path with  "\" doesn't get resolved and gives me errors.

Comment: Are you sure, `PROGRA~1` is the correct one? You shouldn't use short names unless absolutely necessary (not necessary here: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("C:\PROGRAM FILES\Setup\setup.json") do...` or `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("C:\PROGRAM FILES (x86)\Setup\setup.json") do...`)

Comment: @Stephan Yes. I have tried those. but still just prints out the environment variables so figured there can be problem with white space that's why I used PROGRA~1.

Comment: @Stephan I have placed the Setup folder in "Program Files" so there is no point in finding them in Program Files(x86).

Comment: that's why I wrote `or` - as I can't know where you put your files. I showed you a way to work with spaces in folder- or filenames.

Comment: @Stephan   okay. nevermind. I used the ways you suggested to work with spaces in the name; they do not work when the for loop is inside if exist block.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find what was the underlying issue with using "**file read with for loop inside if-exist block**" but I found a workaround using "**goto**" statement.

```
set FILEPATH=C:\\PROGRA~1\\Setup\\setup.json
IF EXIST "%FILEPATH%" (goto getJson)
:getJson
set string=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("C:\Program Files\Setup\setup.json") do set "string=!string!%%x"
echo !string!
```

this code gives the expected output.